# jqplot Linear Chart not displayed in appropriate tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I have a code which has two tabs in one html page.I have to draw a table on one tab and chart on the other.The chart is being displayed in both the tabs .Please read the few lines below the code

```
</head>
<body>

   <div data-role="tabs">
      <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">table</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">Chart</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>


    <div id="one" class="ui-content">

    <style>
         table,th,td
           {
             border:1px solid black;

           }
           th
             {
              background-color:green;
              color:white;
             }
       </style>



       <table id="myTable">


       </table>


       <script>
       var json = //some json data;

       var data = $.parseJSON(json);
       var prices = [];

        for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
       cell1.innerHTML = data[i].date;
        var val = new String(data[i].date);
       var curr_date = val.substr(0,2);
       var curr_month = val.substr(3,2);
       var curr_year = val.substr(6,4);
       var s = "-";

       curr_year = curr_year.concat(s,curr_month,s,curr_date);
       curr_date = "'"+curr_date+"'";

       cell2.innerHTML = data[i].minPrice;
       cell3.innerHTML = data[i].maxPrice;
       var test = [];
       test.push(curr_year,parseInt(data[i].maxPrice));
       prices.push(test);

               }

       </script>



    </div>

    <div id="two" >

   </div>


      <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){


          var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [prices], {
          title:'Price Chart Details',
          axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,label:'Date'},yaxis:
                                              {label:'Price'}},

           series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]

                                                      });
                                  });
      console.log("Chart Drawn");
     </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

i know that the chartdiv is not assosicated to the tabs.If I give the chart container an id "two" it is not at all  displaying the chart , So I am displaying the chart in a container which has not been declared in the page.
It would be great if someone can point the mistake and rectify it